# Сочетания знаков ?"? и ?)?

Tags: пунктуация

При использовании кавычек или скобок нужно ли дублировать вопросительный (восклицательный) знак:

1. Насколько Вам понравилось уведомление "Без чего не может уснуть Соседов?"?
2. Вы собираетесь к Никитиным на ужин (кстати, что будут подавать?)?

Comment: В скобки не желательно ставить полноценный вопрос. В них дополнительная, маловажная информация на всякий случай. А то получается вопрос, на который можно не отвечать, потому что он совсем не важный. Тем более там "кстати", то есть это важно в некоторой степени.

Answer (score 1):

Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации:

> § 200
>
> Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит знак вопросительный, или
> восклицательный, или многоточие, то те же самые знаки не повторяются
> после кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются в силу
> характера соответствующих частей текста, могут ставиться перед
> закрывающими кавычками и после них, например:
>
> Читали ли вы роман Чернышевского «Что делать?»
>
> Но:
>
> Драматический кружок готовит к постановке пьесу «В бой!». Отчего вы
> говорите: «Как бы не так!»?

(Однако *точка повторяется после закрывающих кавычек, если перед ними она употреблена в качестве знака, обозначающего сокращение слова* — Розеналь.)

Что касается скобок, то я **не нашёл запрета на постановку вопросительного и восклицательного знаков и многоточия после скобки, если таким же знаком заканчивается конструкция в скобках**, но в литературе такого дублирования не встречал.

Answer (score 1):

> **§ 159**. При сочетании разных знаков препинания с кавычками действуют правила:
>
> <…>
>
> 3. если перед закрывающей кавычкой стоит знак вопросительный,
>    восклицательный или многоточие (и на этом предложение заканчивается),
>    то те же знаки, необходимые по условиям всего предложения, не
>    повторяются после закрывающей кавычки; неодинаковые знаки (перед
>    кавычкой и после кавычки) ставятся; ср.: *«Вы читали романы «Что
>    делать?» и «Кто виноват ?»; Кто не знает великолепных слов А. Блока:
>    «Сотри случайные черты. И ты увидишь — мир прекрасен...»?; Неужели вы
>    не прочитали роман «Что делать?»!*
>
> http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

Правильно:

**1. *Насколько Вам понравилось*** уведомление ***"Без чего не может уснуть Соседов?"***

Во втором предложении вставку лучше оформить самостоятельным предложением:

**2. *Вы собираетесь к Никитиным на ужин? (Кстати, что будут подавать?)***

P.S. По-моему, слово *уведомление* не совсем правильно применено.

Comment: Что касается "уведомления": мне пришло оно на телефон в виде всплывающего окна с предложением оценить его (это, следовательно, не моя формулировка, а редактора новостного сайта)